# With Android, is it possible to have different layouts for phones and tablets?

Tags: android, android-layout

ok, I know that most current phones and a 7 inch tablet are both considered "large" as far as screen size according to Android. But there's a big difference between a "large" phone with 480x800 pixels and a "large" 7 inch tablet with 800x1280 pixels. I've created separate layouts for those two sizes, but I still haven't wrapped my head around how to get the phone to see the 480x800 layout and have the tablet see the 800x1280 layout. I've tried tweaking the res folder names to things like `layout-large-hdpi` and `layout-large-mdpi`, and also leaving the smaller phone layout as `layout` and the larger, tablet layout as `layout-sw600dp` as the [Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) page suggests, but the problem there becomes Android is still looking in the `drawable-hdpi` for the phone sized images. So the question then is: **How do I declare the phone layouts, and have the phone layout look in the phone drawables folder, and declare the tablet layout and have the layout look in the tablet drawables folder?** I'm targeting Android 3.2 with this app that I'm working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're on the right track.

Stick your phone layouts just in "layout".

Stick your 10" tablet layouts in "layout-sw720dp"

Then use "layout-sw600dp" for targeting 7-inch devices.

You can use the same suffixes for the drawable folders to, so drawable-sw600dp would be targeted at 7" devices. [[Reference](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html)].

Comment: If i could have been able to upvote 100  times, i would love to do on this answer. Great point man.. i was missing !